# OIOSAML: Service endpoint settings issue

Tags: java, single-sign-on, saml-2.0, shibboleth, opensaml

I wrote a simple system with SP-initiating Web SSO scenario based on [OIOSAML](https://svn.softwareborsen.dk/oiosaml.java/sp/trunk/webapp/). To test the system, I deployed it on the remote host.

However `AssertionConsumerServiceURL`, where I specified URL, on which [Shibboleth](https://shibboleth.net/) idP (idP based on Shibboleth) should return the answer is not called.

`SAMLAssertionConsumer` - just a simple servlet, like this:

```
@WebServlet("/saml/consumer")
public class SAMLAssertionConsumer extends HttpServlet {
    @Override
    protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
            throws ServletException, IOException {

        System.out.println(new Date() + " incoming AuthResponse");
    }

    @Override
    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
        response.setContentType("text/html");
        PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();
        out.println("Yes, it worked");

        System.out.println(new Date() + " incoming AuthResponse");
    }
}
```

For a begin with, I just need to make sure that the response comes.

My web.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app id="WebApp_ID" version="3.0"
    metadata-complete="false"     
    xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee/web-app_2_4.xsd" >

    <display-name>OIOSAML-J</display-name>

    <listener>
        <listener-class>dk.itst.oiosaml.sp.service.session.SessionDestroyListener</listener-class>
    </listener>

    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>SAMLDispatcherServlet</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>dk.itst.oiosaml.sp.service.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>

    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>SAMLDispatcherServlet</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/saml/*</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>

    <filter>
        <filter-name>LoginFilter</filter-name>
        <filter-class>dk.itst.oiosaml.sp.service.SPFilter</filter-class>
    </filter>

    <filter-mapping>
        <filter-name>LoginFilter</filter-name>
        <url-pattern>/sp/*</url-pattern>
    </filter-mapping>

    <welcome-file-list>
        <welcome-file>index.jsp</welcome-file>
    </welcome-file-list>

</web-app>
```

My oiosaml-sp.properties:

```
# Properties used by oiosaml-j

# Reference to the location of the certificate used for signing SAML documents with - relative to ${oiosaml.home}
oiosaml-sp.certificate.location=./certificate/keystore

# Opaque/encrypted password to the certificate used for signing SAML documents
oiosaml-sp.certificate.password=some_password

# Required authentication level. 2=password, 3=certificate
oiosaml-sp.assurancelevel=2

# Name of the meta data file for the current service provider - overrides setting in brs-common.properties
common.saml2.metadata.sp.filename=SPMetadata.xml

# URI References to the current service provider
oiosaml-sp.uri.home=

# Whether to validate server certificates. Set to false in production.
# Used for artifact resolution.
oiosaml-sp.resolve.ignorecert=true

# Artifact resolution username and password. Only used the artifact profile is active.
oiosaml-sp.resolve.username=rolf.trifork.com
oiosaml-sp.resolve.password=rolf.trifork.com
```

Generated `AuthnRequest`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<saml2p:AuthnRequest xmlns:saml2p="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:protocol"
                     AssertionConsumerServiceURL="http://ip-of-remote-system-here:8080/saml/consumer"
                     Destination="http://ip-of-identity-provider-here/idp/profile/SAML2/Redirect/SSO" ForceAuthn="false"
                     ID="_31e...341d322d1d" IsPassive="false"
                     IssueInstant="2014-07-11T10:24:43.852Z"
                     ProtocolBinding="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:bindings:HTTP-POST" Version="2.0">
    <saml2:Issuer xmlns:saml2="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:assertion">http://ip-of-remote-system-here:8080</saml2:Issuer>
</saml2p:AuthnRequest>
```

There is some JSP-page private.jsp, I make a request to it:

```
http://ip-of-remote-system-here:8080/sp/private.jsp
```

After this request I redirected to login page of identity provider:

```
http://ip-of-identity-provider-here/idp/Authn/CommonLogin
```

Enter a couple login/password and.. *nothing*. Opens page with description of some common error:

```
http://ip-of-identity-provider-here/idp/Authn/UsernamePasswordLogin
```

> error
>
> An error occurred while request processing.

Does not work and my servlet `SAMLAssertionConsumer`, the console is clear. But if I make request to my servlet `SAMLAssertionConsumer` direct:

```
http://ip-of-remote-system-here:8080/saml/consumer
```

Then it works. Of course.

I would like to know how to properly configure the the assertion consumer service. That is the part of the SP-metadata, where I specify the assertion consumer.

```
<md:EntityDescriptor xmlns:md="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:metadata" xmlns:saml="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:assertion" xmlns:esia="urn:esia:shibboleth:2.0:mdext" entityID="http://ip-of-remote-system-here:8080">
...
<md:SingleLogoutService Binding="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:bindings:HTTP-Redirect"  Location="http://ip-of-remote-system-here:8080/saml/consumer" ResponseLocation="http://ip-of-remote-system-here:8080/saml/consumer"/>
<md:AssertionConsumerService Binding="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:bindings:HTTP-POST" Location="http://ip-of-remote-system-here:8080/saml/consumer" index="0" isDefault="true"/>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was different. Was used incorrect keystore. Now everything is OK.

Initially, I assumed that `entityID` attribute must refer to a domain name, which specified in attributes `Location`. However, it is not. It just must be unique and it is better to use domain name for that.

[UnderstandingShibboleth, EntityNaming:](https://wiki.shibboleth.net/confluence/display/SHIB2/EntityNaming)

> Shibboleth identity and service providers are used in SAML
>   deployments, and as such,  they are assigned a unique name known as an
>   "entityID".

[Metadata for the OASIS Security Assertion Markup Language (SAML)V2.0, 2.3.2 Element :](http://docs.oasis-open.org/security/saml/v2.0/saml-metadata-2.0-os.pdf)

> `entityID` [Required] -
>
> ```
>  Specifies the unique identifier of the SAML entity whose metadata is 
>  described by the element's contents.
> ```

[UnderstandingShibboleth, EntityNaming:](https://wiki.shibboleth.net/confluence/display/SHIB2/EntityNaming)

> Strongly recommended NOT to use the physical hostname of a server
>   running Shibboleth as the `entityID`. As time passes, things get moved
>   and that deployment may not always live on the same box.
>
> Additionally there may be multiple logical deployments of Shibboleth
>   on a single physical server, each requiring their own unique
>   `entityID`, so using the server's name doesn't scale beyond a single
>   one.

In the sandbox can be use physical addresses.